# Retrieve values from within autoID node

Tags: swift, firebase

I would like to get the values from within a autoID node. Below is my structure:

```
"workout"
  "exercise"
    "Bench Press"
      "(AutoIDNode)"
        "reps: 10"
        "set: 1"
        "weight: 60"
```

How can I get the values of "reps", "set" and "weight".

Here is my swift code:

```
refSets.child("workout").child("exercise").child("Bench Press").observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
            self.setsData.removeAll()

            for sets in snapshot.children {
                let snap = sets as! DataSnapshot
                let key = snap.key
                let value = snap.value
                print(key)
                print(value!)
            }     
        }
    })
```

I am aware I am missing the .child() path for the autoID node following .child("Bench Press"). How can I access this node?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
refSets.child("workout").child("exercise").child("Bench Press").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

    if let res = snapshot.value as? [String:[String:Int]] {

        for item in Array(res.values) {

            print(item["reps"])
        }

    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

What about that?

```
refSets
  .child("workout")
  .child("exercise")
  .child("Bench Press").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
    guard let values = snapshot.value as [String: Any] else {
      return
    }

    for (key, value) in values {
      guard let objDict = value as? [String: Any], 
        let reps = objDict["reps"] as? Double /*not sure maybe Int*/,
        let set = objDict["set"] as? Double,
        let weight = objDict["weight"] as? Double else {
        continue 
      }
      let bp = BenchPress(reps: reps, set: set, weight: weight)

    }
  })

struct BenchPress {

  private let reps: Double
  private let set: Double
  private let weight: Double

  init(reps: Double, set: Double, weight: Double) {

    self.reps = reps
    self.set = set
    self.weight = weight
  }
}
```